# Deploying grails application to Heroku

Tags: grails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy Grails application to Heroku for the first time , and it's successfully deployed as per their log :

```
 |Done creating WAR target/PatientBoards-0.1.war
 -----> No server directory found. Adding webapp-runner 7.0.57.2 automatically.
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> (none)
   Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing... done, 132.4MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
   https://patientboards.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

But when I go to https://patientboards.herokuapp.com the page is blank ! although i tried it locally and the application is working fine .

i found this in the log:

```
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752616+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Illegal access: this   web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
 2015-11-24T23:22:38.752617+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalStateException
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752618+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752618+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
 2015-11-24T23:22:38.752619+00:00 app[web.1]:    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.keySet(DiskStore.java:610)
 2015-11-24T23:22:38.752624+00:00 app[web.1]:    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:817)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752625+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752647+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752648+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752648+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752649+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752649+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752650+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-24T23:22:38.752651+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811300+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 24, 2015 11:25:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811307+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811309+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalStateException
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811310+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811311+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811312+00:00 app[web.1]:    at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.iterator(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3252)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811312+00:00 app[web.1]:    at net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl$1.run(ExtendedStatisticsImpl.java:104)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811313+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811314+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811315+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811315+00:00 app[web.1]:  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811316+00:00 app[web.1]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811317+00:00 app[web.1]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811318+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-24T23:25:38.811319+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-11-24T23:27:24.541959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=patientboards.herokuapp.com request_id=264982a9-7c89-492d-bf01-0aa72639cd75 fwd="176.61.71.119" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=404 bytes=128
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: So the error points to ehcache. I have little experience with that plugin but the first exception suggests to me that it's trying to persist to disk. Heroku may not allow that. If that's the case, I believe the plugin can persist to RAM.

Comment: but i'm not using the ehcache plugin in my application

Comment: Your app may not be using it directly. You can confirm with the Grails dependency-report command: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html